# How to construct Spring Data repository query two Parameters with IN and same list?

Tags: sql, spring, repository

This is my Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(EtlJobExecutionTriggersId.class)
@Table(name = "ETL_JOB_EXEC_TRIGGERS")
public class EtlJobExecutionTriggers {
    @Id private Long jobExecIdUs;
    @Id private Long jobExecIdDs;
    private LocalDate cobDate;
}
```

And here is the Composite Primary Key Class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class EtlJobExecutionTriggersId implements Serializable {
    private Long jobExecIdUs;
    private Long jobExecIdDs;
}
```

And here is my Spring Repo:

```
public interface EtlJobExecTriggersRepo extends JpaRepository<EtlJobExecutionTriggers, EtlJobExecutionTriggersId> {
        String SQL_ = "select o from EtlJobExecutionTriggers o where o.jobExecIdDs in (:ids) or o.jobExecIdUs in (:ids) order by o.jobExecIdUs, o.jobExecIdDs";
        @Query(EtlJobExecTriggersRepo.SQL_)
        List<EtlJobExecutionTriggers> findAllByJobExecIdDsInAndJobExecIdUsInSQL(@Param("ids") List<Long> jobExecIdList);
    }
```

The @Query works as expected, but I would like not to write any SQL and instead express the same Query using only Spring Data repository query.

I have tried the following (and other variants)

```
List<EtlJobExecutionTriggers> findAllByJobExecIdDsInAndJobExecIdUsInOrderByJobExecIdUsJobExecIdDs(List<Long> jobExecIdDsList)
```

But i keep getting errors when Booting. The above interface method yields the following exception for the OrderBy part:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property jobExecIdDs found for type Long! Traversed path: EtlJobExecutionTriggers.jobExecIdUs.
```

So what am I doing wrong here? or is it not possible to express this particular query via Spring Data Repo query?

As I have written in my comment I fixed the Order by issue, but I am still unable to make it work with only one method parameter **(List jobExecIdList**)

When I make it with two (**List jobExecIdDsList, List jobExecIdUsList**)

Like this:

```
List<EtlJobExecutionTriggers> findAllByJobExecIdDsInAndJobExecIdUsInOrderByJobExecIdUsAscJobExecIdDsAsc(List<Long> jobExecIdDsList, List<Long> jobExecIdUsList);
```

it actually works but I can't get to work with only one list, as in the @Query("....") method

Comment: Fixed the Order by issue - I had to add "direction" between the Order by (Asc / Desc) parameters like this:  findAllByJobExecIdDsInAndJobExecIdUsInOrderByJobExecIdUsAscJobExecIdDsAsc

Answer (score 0):

I think using your own custom id generator conflicts with Spring Data Repository query.

Answer (score 0):

// You shoud have two parameters in your method as below.
List findAllByJobExecIdDsInAndJobExecIdUsInOrderByJobExecIdUsJobExecIdDs(List jobExecIdDsList,List jobExecIdUsList);

Comment: Yes, that works (I just updated that to the question), so I can do it with Spring Data repo query (get same result) but not in the same way with only one parameter?